# Condition expression will always return true value on Install4j

Tags: install4j

We have a "*Run script*" action in which we set new installation variables.

The "*isOnWindows*" variable should holds the value whether we running on windows or not:
 `context.setVariable("isOnWindows", context.getVariable("sys.windowsDir") != null);`

In the `installation.log` I can see that when running on windows, the variable value is `true`.
My problem is that Linux actions are running as well together with windows. The "*Condition expression*" in Linux is `!context.getBooleanVariable("isOnWindows")` - so why these actions are getting running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether you are running on Windows, use `Util.isWindows()`

Otherwise, if you have a problem with condition expressions, I would try to add logging output to them.